# How to tell when a player isn't moving?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a away to test if a player isn't moving?

At the moment I have put this command on a hopper clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @a sneak 3
```

But that doesn't seem to work because in another command block I am testing for a score of three, and every tick it summons a block even when you're moving.

I am using this for a vanilla block hunt so when your not moving you become a solid block.

Answer (score 4):

@132ikl's answer works in general, but there is a flaw to the design: `stat.walkOneCm` does not increase while you are in mid-air. We can fix this by assuming every player that is in mid-air is moving.

Create the scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Moving stat.walkOneCm
```

Create a 20Hz clock or use repeat/chain command blocks and run the following two commands:

```
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_Moving_min=1] Moving 1 {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Moving_min=1] Moving 1
```

The first command will reduce the `Moving` score by one for every player on the ground, if it is at least 1 (I.e. the score will not go below 0).
The second command limits the `Moving` score to at most 1 by setting it to one if it is greater.

`Moving` will be 1 for people that are moving, or were moving prior to jumping (jumping in place does not work), and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Create two scoreboards:

```
/scoreboard objectives add walk stat.walkOneCm  
/scoreboard objectives add moving dummy
```

Step 2: Make a command block clock with these commands:

```
/scoreboard players set @a walk 0
/scoreboard players set @a[score_walk_min=1] moving 1
```

Then everyone that is not walking will have a moving score of 0

Comment: do you mean a 20 tsp clock

Comment: http://www.minecraftworldmap.com/worlds/5fWG4

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgdi6ntp2t7qr6l/Demo%20World%20%28Assley%20Gaming%29.zip?dl=1

Comment: k thanks do you take the out put form the walk command