# Testfor movement after Eating

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having trouble with commandblocks, so here is what I want to do:
I want to create a system that teleports you away upon eating bread. I know how to test for a player who is eating the bread using:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Eat stat.useItem.minecraft.bread  
/testfor @a[score_Eat_min=1]  
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Eat_min=1] Eat 0
```

That part for me is easy, but I also want to add a feature that you won't be teleported away if you are moving, or moving after you have eaten the bread. This part I do not know how to create with commandblocks. I want this only to happen for the player who ate the bread and not that it will count the movements of other players.

Comment: Check out this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC3dt83pFjk, and invert the signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, follow the steps in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244810/112767):

Create the scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Moving stat.walkOneCm
```

Create a 20Hz clock or use repeat/chain command blocks and run the following two commands:

```
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_Moving_min=1] Moving 1 {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Moving_min=1] Moving 1
```

The first command will reduce the Moving score by one for every player on the ground, if it is at least 1 (I.e. the score will not go below 0).
The second command limits the Moving score to at most 1 by setting it to one if it is greater.

Moving will be 1 for people that are moving, or were moving prior to jumping (jumping in place does not work), and 0 otherwise.

*Now from me*:
Next hook up this command block to the system that detects the player eating bread:

```
tp @a[score_Moving=0,score_Moving_min=0] x y z
```

Basically, this tests if the score `Moving` (Remember, `0` is not moving, and `1` is) is `0`. If it is `0`, that means the player is *not* moving, and hence teleports them.

TIP: Maybe, you should run the previous command a few times after the player eats the bread, to make sure that don't move at all after they eat the bread.

Hope I helped!